# How to populate a calendar template with dates in the right place with Swift3?

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, nsdate, nscalendar

I was thinking of finding the first day of the week and filling in from there, but how could I change the day number to be the 1st instead of the current? It sounded like `calendar.firstWeekday` might have done the trick but the docs say literally nothing about how it works and it returns `1` which definitely isn't Wednesday (Feb 1st, 2017). Tried changing `now` and `calendar` to `var`s and seeing if I could something along the lines of .setDay on them but haven't found anything.

```
    let now = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .weekday], from: date)

    // 1 = Sunday, 7 = Saturday
    print("day of week: ")
    print(components.weekday)
```

However, using Swift's Date and Calendar, is there an easier way to do this than finding the first day and filling in the rest of the calendar from there? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You only need to calculate the weekday for the 1st of the month. Then it's trivial to fill In the rest of the month.

Comment: That was my initial thought. Get the current year and month and find what day of the week the 1st falls on then go from there. Was curious if there was a better way though, especially using something built in with Swift

Answer (score 0):

[Foundation Calendar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar) should allow you to do pretty much whatever you want.

If you want to get fancy, you could build something that takes a date and returns a Type (I would recommend a struct) with the date/weekday/etc. info in it for easy display/organization.

Comment: How could I force the `day` component to be the 1st?

Comment: You should be able to use this or one of the similar methods: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar/2293676-date

Comment: FYI, I would recommend using playgrounds until you have things figured out when doing date manipulation. Some of the APIs can be a bit confusing, so the instant feedback is really helpful.